# How to create an auto-scaling grid-layout with breakpoint? (Card with image and content next to each other)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid

I read [Modern CSS grid solutions to common layout problems](https://vycke.dev/blog/css-layout-patterns/) and try to create the discussed two-way card layout.

[Codepen see here](https://codepen.io/dash/pen/ExyeVLq).

With the code below, on smaller screens the `<p>` text overflows the image instead of breaking into a new line if there is not enough space:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/Abq5QUn.png]

Any ideas how to make the paragraph wrap if there is not enough space instead of overlapping?

**Code:**

```
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
    minmax(2rem, 1fr)
    minmax(auto, 65ch)
    minmax(2rem, 1fr);
}

/* Center all children */
article > * {
  grid-column: 2;
}

/* Wider & centered images */
article > img {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100ch;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20rem, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  width: 100%;
}

<article>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
</article>
<div class=grid>
   
<img src=https://via.placeholder.com/400x400 alt>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector for your image does not work. Your img is not a child of article, as the css describes.